# Installing postgresql db together with python package

Tags: python, postgresql, packaging

I wrote a python script that requires the use of a postgresql DB. For test purpose, I installed the postgresql DB manually, and the DB that comes with that. The script connects to it and make its job.
My question is about packaging : what is the best solution for the user to install this script, along with the DB and its schema juste by typing pip install xxx ?
Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: "what is the best solution for the user to install this script, along with the DB and its schema juste by typing pip install xxx"—the best solution is _not_ to do that. Postgres is a complex product that may require careful tuning. Your users may already have it installed somewhere, or may prefer to use it from a Docker container, or may want to point to a hosted cloud instance like Azure Database for PostgreSQL or to use a specific version or any number of other things. Let them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is great but often you can get away with [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). It's part of the standard library and comes bundled with Python

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I choose SQLite, that is exactly what I need for this scenario, I was not aware of this very simple DB, that's perfect !